# Error while running jar file on system

Tags: java, jar

I am having a java file like the following:

```
import org.xBaseJ.DBF;
import org.xBaseJ.fields.CharField;
import org.xBaseJ.fields.NumField;
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Example2 {

public static void main(String args[]){
..........
}
}
```

I have created the this to 'Example2.jar' file to run   by following the steps below:

```
1) javac Example2.java
2) java Example2
3) This will produce a .class file needed for the JAR file.

4) Next create a manifest file (saved using the extension .txt) using the text editor and input        the following

Main-Class: Example2
or whatever your file's name is.

5) Next create the JAR file using this code:

jar cfe Example2.jar Example2 Example2.class
```

After step 5, I got a jar file named 'Example2.jar' . I tried to run the jar file  using the following command:

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

But I am getting the following Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xBaseJ/DBF          at            Example2.main(Example2.java:14)                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xBaseJ.DBF                        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)                  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)                  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)              at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                   ... 1 more
```

I did not understand, what is the reason? Please guide me?

Comment: Make sure you have xBaseJ API in .classpath

Comment: @Parfait I have Extracted the xBaseJ API jar and make it a folder as jar and then doing the manipulations. I didnt set classpath

Comment: I think the reason is its not able to find the class file which is generated so that is why its giving error. and from where u running this jar and is it containing any external libraries. ?

Comment: @Krishna I am running from the same location where my org folder and my java file resides

Comment: @androidGenX are u using netbeans?

Comment: @androidGenX are u having any external dependencies in your class i mean do u using any api in that java file?

Comment: @Krishna yes, I am using xbasej api, which jar file I have set on my classpath

Comment: @Parfait I have already added xBaseJ API jar file on my class path

Comment: @androidGenX means into the jdk Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63265/discussion-between-androidgenx-and-krishna).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one thing is that when u are creating Jar just look this menifest first that is what can help for the including the External Libraries.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
```

While creating and giving chages to the menifest just have to run that class with the configuration

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html
```

so seeing both of that link.

just look this Example.

run your java and get class file

```
javac Test.java
```

and if u having some other external libraries working then do like this.

```
javac -classpath xxx.jar Test.java
```

and see the menifest configuration and make that file with external changes like this.

```
menifest.txt
Main-Class: Test
Class-Path: xxx.jar xxxx.jar
```

then u need to make jar file like this.
   run this command

```
jar cfm jarName.jar manifest.txt Test.class
```

and hence we done u can have jarfile in that same path.

Comment: if u need to have it dynamically then u need to code for it. like what ever your jars are then u need to put it. but to prevent that complex process i strongly command u to use IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is caused by having an incorrect [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). I'm assuming that when you compiled the class, you somehow provided a classpath (either by passing the '-classpath' arg or by setting the 'CLASSPATH' environment variable). The problem is that the *compilation* classpath is separate from the *runtime* classpath. So, you just need to ensure that all of the dependencies (other jar files, most likely) that were on the classpath when you *compiled* the class are also added to the classpath when *running* the jar. For a jar file, this is typically done by [adding a 'Class-Path'header to the manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

An alternative method would be to specify the classpath using either the command line arg or the environment variable and include your Example2.jar file in that classpath, and run `java Example2` (without the '-jar').

Comment: I want to package my file as jar  and it should work on client machine. It is working fine with java Example2 , but when I created jar then only it shows this errors

Comment: I have added all class path